# Remove a given number of elements with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 10 divs with the same name class example `my-div`. 
When an event is triggered in a change of a select input I want to remove the number of that divs pair to the number of the input.

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

**Html**

```
<select id="delete">
   <option value="0">0</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<div class="my-div"></div>
<div class="my-div"></div>
<div class="my-div"></div>
<div class="my-div"></div>
<div class="my-div"></div>
<div class="my-div"></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).on('change','#delete',function(){

   var value = $(this).val();

   // here I need to remove the divs pair the variable value

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use jQuery [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get the number you want:

```
$(document).on('change','#delete',function(){
    var value = parseInt($(this).val());
    if (value > 0) {
        $('.my-div').slice(0, value).remove();
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5de6q/)

Comment: Yes exactly, this one is what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
$(document).on('change','#delete',function(){
   var value = +$(this).val();
   $('.my-div:lt(' + value + ')').remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VE7uu/1/

Comment: Thanks for the example, but is not the goal that i was trying to achieve. I wanted delete the number of divs pair to the value of the input, means if the value is 3, I want to delete three divs :). But for sure my question was not clear 100%

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove, or do you just want to hide? Literally removing the `div`s will add a bit complexity to your logic if, say, you select a `1` and then go back to `4`.

If all you want is *hide*, then you can try something like this:

```
var divs = $('.my-divs');

// this way of tacking on events is kinda inefficient, btw
$(document).on('change', '#delete', function () {
    var idx = +($(this).val());
    divs.show()
        .filter(':gt(' + idx + ')')
        .hide()
        ;
});
```